# lights off in one room, other rooms in the same circuit are fine, no GFCI, breaker not tripped

Tags: electrical

It was caused by a short circuit, I think I heard a "pop" sound, so I thought it might be the dimmer got blown up. But the lights are still off even with new dimmer and new switch. 100% sure no GFCI, mcb didn't not turn off since other rooms are doing fine. Could please someone help?

Comment: Did you recently change out the light bulbs in the fixture? The reason I am asking is because many new fixtures have a fuse link in the fixture that prevents higher wattage lamps from being installed rather than the recommended lamp and wattage.

Comment: are the outlets out in that room too?

Comment: @JACK outlets are in different circuit

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician yes, the short circuit happend during bulb/transform changing.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician the short circuit happend during bulb/transformer changing. there were seven working bulbs (all low voltage halogen), now none of them working, I just asume the bulbs in parallel circuit shouldn't be affected. I couldn't test if they were burn out, since I don't want to touch them by myself anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's very typical for power surges -- either temporary shorts, or simply plugging in a high draw appliance for the first time -- to "blow out" a wire termination - typically at a receptacle or switch.

Usually, the blown out connection is a "backstab" aka back-wire connection.  This is one big reason we do not like backstabs on this stack.  Occasionally the failure can be in a screw connection (one very badly done) or a wire-nut connection (typically also very badly done, and likely secured with tape because the person wasn't very good at wire nutting, and had to hold it together with tape to keep it from falling apart).

The failure must be at the last working outlet in the chain, or the first defective outlet.  The "chain" being the wire jumps from the breaker panel to this outlet.

Comment: Hi Harper, thans for your reply. So you mean it is the switch or dimmer got blown up? but I have bought a new switch（same type) and a new dimmer (different brand and new one is universal), still no working. the short circuit happend during bulb/transformer changing. there were seven working bulbs (all low voltage halogen), now none of them working, I just asume the bulbs in parallel circuit shouldn't be affected. I couldn't test if they were burn out, since I don't want to touch them by myself anymore. could you please tell me how big is the chance of a burn out wire in the wall?

Comment: "we do not like backstabs" - is that the royal, or the editorial "we"?  (In other words, *you* do not like backstabs, other people have different views about them.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica -- that's a fairly consistent position across the "big name" users in [electrical]

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica ...because... of the problems I mentioned, and the way it creates frustrating "bug hunts" or worse, genuine arcing problems. Not least, they are uninspectable - you cannot eyeball a backstab to see if it is the failed one. You have to take it apart, *and they can't be used twice*, so now you must either switch to screws or replace the receptacle..

Answer (score 1):

If the lamps are standard "edison" (screw) connection my idea is that the little metal contacts inside the lampholder bent and now form a short-circuit.

After you disconnected main power from the chandelier, look inside the lampholder and see if the side contact touches the bottom one, if so that's the short circuit.

See if you can put the contact in it's regoular position, if not, it's time to replace the lampholder.

Comment: Hi DDS, thanks for your reply. could you please tell me how big is the chance of a burn out wire in the wall? also I have 8 lamps in one circuit and if I disconnected the first or the last one(pull the wires out of the lampholder and not connect them at all), then even every device is in perfect condition still there will be no lignt being turned on, right?